# Write in google calendar via API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-calendar-api

```js
var text = $('#text').val(); //title of Event
var key  = $('#key').val(); //my calendar-api key to connect to my google-calendar
var url  = "https://content.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/example%40gmail.com/events/quickAdd?text="+text+"&key="+key;

$.ajax({
  url : url,
  type: "POST",
  success: function(data)
  {
    console.log(data);
  },
});
```

response message says **"message": "Login Required"**
I am not sure what's wrong with it???

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Google Calendar API, you not only need the client ID , you also need to have your user authenticated. one way to achieve that is to use  [OAuth2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

You may use client library that you can  [download](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/downloads). There are 6 languages supported library's. Also, there is an example on how to use the library  [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#loading-an-api-and-making-a-request) which demonstrate the library's functionality.